# How to set assign target to GVRHead GoogleVR

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

I am working with the Google Cardboard plugin in Unity 3D (version 5.3.2). I have a C# script set up that is supposed to access the variable "target" from the script "GvrHead.cs". This is the part of the script (it is called "CrystalDrop.cs"):

```
        12. public Transform target2;
        13. private GameObject HeadObj;
        14. private GvrHead myScript;
        15.
        16.
        17. void Start () {
        18.     HeadObj = GameObject.Find ("GvrHeadObj");
        19.     myScript = HeadObj.GetComponent(GvrHead);
        20.     myScript.target = target2;
        21. }
```

But when I run the project in Unity, I get this error:

Assets/CrystalDrop.cs(19,49): error CS0119: Expression denotes a `type`, where a `variable`, `value` or `method group` was expected.

Does anybody know what is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
    12. public Transform target2;
    13. private GameObject HeadObj;
    14. private GvrHead myScript;
    15.
    16.
    17. void Start () {
    18.     GvrHead.target = target2;
    21. }
```

Comment: The answer you had before you edited it worked, actually. When it said: GvrHead.target = target2;. If you change it back I'll mark as accepted answer.

Comment: @HenryV I changed it back now. I was not sure if the `target` variable is static or not. I just checked documentation of GVR and its not static thats why I reverted it back. Have Fun :)

Comment: Thanks, I manually changed it to static. Accepted and upvoted! :)

Comment: Glad to be helpful :) However I won't recommend you to change code from classes included in SDK

Answer (score 1):

Simply change `myScript = HeadObj.GetComponent(GvrHead);` to `myScript = HeadObj.GetComponent<GvrHead>();`. That's how to get component with C#, in Unity.

Comment: I did that, and now it is saying: Assets/CrystalDrop.cs(19,17): error CS0428: Cannot convert method group `GetComponent` to non-delegate type `GvrHead`. Consider using parentheses to invoke the method

Comment: So it wants me to use parenthesis again, which would just give me that error again.

Comment: You need to use both the angle brackets and parentheses at the end (empty) - exactly as stated by @Programmer

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't see that. But when I change that part, it just says: Assets/CrystalDrop.cs(20,26): error CS0176: Static member `GvrHead.target` cannot be accessed with an instance reference, qualify it with a type name instead

Comment: @HenryV check my answer

Comment: @UmairM Your answer is the-same as mine. You basically posted the-same thing I have in my answer.

Comment: @Programmer YES! sometimes it is easy to get the meaning from code rather than words

Comment: @UmairM **" it is easy to get the meaning from code rather than words"** That doesn't make sense. I provided a code that solves the error he's having...`myScript = HeadObj.GetComponent<GvrHead>();` Did you see that? There is no reason to re-post the whole code if the problem is just one line of code. Just fix the line of code with the problem. Anyways, happy coding!

Comment: I was not talking about the code part of your answer. I have experienced this a lot that beginners do not get it unless you tell them something to compare with what they have. :)

Answer (score 1):

Make private GvrHead myScript; to public GvrHead myScript; then the drag and drop the game object with GvrHead script.that might work